# Как обрабатывать запросы POST и GET в Elixir?

Tags: servlet, elixir

Необходимо на Elixir реализовать веб-приложение, обрабатывающее два вида запросов:

```
POST /data_in
{
"data": [
"https://ya.ru",
"https://ya.ru?q=123",
"yandex.ru",
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828270/how-to-exit-the-vim-editor"
]
}
```

и

```
GET /data_out?from=1545221231&to=1545217638
```

По запросу POST нужно данные из тела запроса положить в хранилище. По запросу GET необходимо передать данные из хранилища.
Вопрос: как веб-приложение общается с сервером? Нужно "слушать" какой-нибудь порт? Использовать Phoenix? Или Poison? Или пользоваться Plug и Cowboy? Как веб-приложение связывается с "внешним миром"? Где об этом можно прочитать/посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнения данной задачи из перечисленного потребуется только `Plug + Cowboy`.
Пример создания простого веб-сервера есть [на Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/ru/lessons/specifics/plug/).
Веб-сервер запустится на указанном в конфигурации порту.

`Poison` может быть использован для парсинга JSON.

---

Для "общения с внешним миром" могут быть использованы любые HTTP-клиенты, например:

- [HTTPoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison)
- [HTTPotion](https://github.com/myfreeweb/httpotion)
- [Tesla](https://github.com/teamon/tesla)